# Alternative to .load() for a mobile website

Tags: jquery, mobile, web

I'm loading content into a div wrapper using javascript .load() funciton and its not working in dolphin mobile browser on android.  So I have:

```
$('#wrapper').load('content.php');
```

This crashes the website.  It works on mobile safari on an iphone.  Is there an alternative to this code?

Comment: Do you know why it crashes? If you don't know why you have no criteria to select an alternative method. Maybe the HTML result is too big and your browser runs out of memory? It could really be that simple.

Comment: @JosephSilber jQuery is also made from JS! You have to solve problem not to point out about tags!

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get('content.php', function(data) {
$('#wrapper').html(data);
});
```

Comment: hmmm. its still crashing on android borwsers and not safari.  I've stripped out almost everything other than the above snippet and it stil crashes.